# how to send array values through url in PHP?

Tags: php, url

how to send array through url in PHP?

I have an array of product ids i want to use these id through url because this is the osCommerce needs it in which i am working in, how can i do it?

Generally osCommerce asks for the single product insertion which in turn gives me back a product id which i pass into the url and get it in shopping cart where i am shown this added product, but now i have multiple products added in first page with different generated product ids and i have to display these products the same way they are displayed in genaral, for which i will need all these generated ids here in url

Comment: That really depends on what you need to do with it. More information is needed in order to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your looking for [http_build_query()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Example from php.net:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data);
// foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor

echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
// foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

Answer (score 7):

?arr[]=abc&arr[]=pqr&arr[]=xyz&arr[]=xxx

Answer (score 3):

well what i would do is `json_encode`([php json](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) the array and assign that to a variable in php. you can then `urlencode` the variable to send it via the url. On the other end you can `json_decode`. Do look up for json if you are not aware of it. its very powerful and useful though.

Answer (score 1):

You can either [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it or send it as `?a[]=1&a[]=val2&someOtherArg=val`. This will give a `$_GET` array like:

```
array(
    'a' => array(
        0 => '1',
        1 => 'val2',
    ),
    'someOtherArg' => 'val'
)
```

Do note, however, that you should probably keep your entire query below ~2k characters. ([more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues))

Answer (score 0):

If you are POST-ing data, then name your fields with PHP array-style syntax:

```
<input type="text" name="myArray[]" value="A">
<input type="text" name="myArray[]" value="B">
<input type="text" name="myArray[]" value="C">
```

If you want to pass the data in a GET request, you can separate the data and split it server side using explode:

```
page.php?myData=A,B,C,D
```

...

```
$myArray = explode(',', $_POST['myData']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to encode them like this:

http://your.url/page.php?myArray[0]=val1&myArray[1]=val2

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the product IDs in an array, then you can use the `http_build_query()` function, which will encode the array like thus:

`http://www.example.com/?pid[]=1&pid[]=2&pid[]=3 ...`

Hope that helps.