# Nested ID from the url needed

Tags: php, jquery, url

I need to get an `ID` which is displayed in the `URL`.
I can access the `ID's` by using the `$_GET` in `php` but when they are nested as shown in the example below I can't get can't the `ID`...

example:

```
index.php?id[sub1]=1789&id[sub2]=1789
```

I would be very happy if someone could help with using `php` or `jQuery` for a solution.

Comment: `index.php?id[]=1789&id[]=1789` it should work without the key, then id should be a valid array in $_GET, not sure if I got you correctly

Comment: please check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093100/how-to-send-array-values-through-url-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093100/how-to-send-array-values-through-url-in-php)

Comment: how about, `echo $_GET['id']['sub1'];` and `echo $_GET['id']['sub2'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ID is always the same:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = is_array($_GET['id']) ? current($_GET['id']) : $_GET['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str="index.php?id[sub1]=1789&id[sub2]=1789";

$x=parse_str($str,$out);


print_r($out); //loop through this

Array
(
    [index_php?id] => Array
        (
            [sub1] => 1789
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [sub2] => 1789
        )

)
```