# Capturing cloned row values for AJAX send

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I currently have a simple table with 4 columns and one row. The user can fill in the data for the 4 columns and submit my javascript function finds the value based on the id. Simple. The user also has the option to add another row and input more data. When the row is cloned it maintains the ID of the parent row.

Where I am running into trouble is how to capture the values of the cloned rows.

Im currently using this to capture the value of one of the input elements:

```
var fineexpense= document.getElementById('fineexpense').value;
```

When I have multiple rows, it only grabs the first value.

What would be the best way to turn all the values with that ID into an array then send it via AJAX?

Im really stumped with how to do this with Javascript. Any help would be great! Thank you.

This is my cloning function : (needs to be edited to change ID)

```
function add() {

  var row = document.getElementById("finerow"); // find row to copy
  var table = document.getElementById("adddate"); // find table to append to
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
 // clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
  table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

This is a sample of my HTML:

```
<table  class="tablesorter2"> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr id='finerow'> 
            <td>Expense:
            </td>

            <td>
              <select id="fineexpense" name='fineexpense'>
              <option value='Mortage/Rent'>Mortage/Rent
              </option>
              <option value='Auto'>Auto
              </option>
```

Comment: "_When the row is cloned it maintains the ID of the parent row_"  So are you saying that you duplicate the row, resulting in two table rows which have the _same_ id? If so, that isn't allowed. `id` attributes must be unique to the document, and so the behavior you see with `getElementById()` returning only one is correct.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code which clones rows, and a sample of what the HTML markup looks like before and afterward.

Comment: Thats what Im learning. My logic would be, getElementById() for each new row and have the row id increase with each cloning. But the amount of rows is completely variable, so preprograming get values from rows that may or may not exist seems stupid, and what if I don't expect enough cloning? then the value never gets captured. Obviously this isn't acceptable. So the whole process of cloning and capturing is what I need to be tough. Thank you for your response

Comment: Instead of relying on `id`, you may add a class or a `data-` attribute, neither of which needs to be unique. In any case, we can help you sort this out if you post a bit more of the JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, Just posted some Javascript for you. Thanks a lot Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ID(s) should be unique. If you have multiple same element(cloned element), then using class definition is more suitable for this.

> When I have multiple rows, it only grabs the first value.

Yes, this happen because the ID(s) only capture the first element found. Here  i give solution for you, let say you have multiple element like below :

```
<input type="text" name="myName" class="sameElement" value="a">
<input type="text" name="myName" class="sameElement" value="b">
<input type="text" name="myName" class="sameElement" value="c">
```

So, instead of using id, we use class for these. Then you can using [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to capture all the value for these element and store inside array variable like so :

```
var allValue = [];

$('.sameElement').each(function(){
    allValue.push( $(this).val() ); //output <-- ['a','b','c']
});
```

Or you can use javascript object as they have key and pair for easy understanding. This is just an example on how to play with multiple element.

Well, if you wanna send this value via ajax, here is simple example :

```
 $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'url_for_processing',
    data : {
      myVar : allValue //<-- we passed an array value
    },
    success : function(data) {
      // do whatever you want
    }
 });
```

Comment: So far this is working. Is there anything special I have to do to send an array through the URL? And I'm guessing my request variable in PHP will will just be an array type, then cake from there. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer this question. Very helpful.

Comment: So many out there to send through URL, Here is another example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093100/how-to-send-array-values-through-url-in-php. And you're welcome :)